# Panel problem in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

I created a panel and I added a link to other form using the code

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint    

        AdminLogin.TopLevel = False
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(AdminLogin)
        AdminLogin.Show()

 End Sub
```

The panel is displaying the adminlogin form which is inside the panel but when I click any buttons inside the adminlogin the adminlogin form blinks.
Why this blink is occurring ? how can I stop it?I had also added me.refresh inside the panel but it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

> Why this blink is occurring ?

It is blinking because you are adding a control every paint the panel which happens when you click on a button.

> how can I stop it?

You only add the control if it is not already been added.

Of course this doesn't mean your overal design isn't flawed.

Comment: @Ramhound- Not understood how to stop it ?please explain in detail

Comment: @Frozen - What exactly don't you understand?  Everytime you add a control to the panel the control is drawn again.  The solution is to only add the control once.  You have not posted your attempt after I told you the reason it is blinking.

Comment: What attempts should I do ?Is their any way?

Comment: @Frozen - Check if the control already exists on the panel if it doesn't then don't add the control.